# Inserting information from one webpage to two different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am working in asp.net and i have a User page with text boxes and submit button. When a user enters information to text boxes and press the button, the information is added to sql server database User table. After adding the information to database, the user is redirected to another page(`Response. Redirect()`), where the user is asked to chose the information from drop down menu and click button. After button is clicked i want to add the information from drop down to another table(WorkShop) but i need also some information from text boxes on the User Page to be added to Work shop table. Can any body help me? Thank you

Comment: You want to have a server control (button) that when you pressed the submit button, the records will be saved to two different tables. Is that correct?

Comment: No, there are two different page, each has its own submit button. Each button sends data to only one database.

Comment: Ah okay. Try to use session state as suggested by Anil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Session State to keep your records even if you use response.redirect. I suggest you to look [Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Here is a sample code for Session. You can reach from every page to this values by using session state. But it only works if you use user sessions!. Another way to transfer a data from pages is to use querystring. Try to look at [Querystring ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

```
Session["FirstName"] = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
Session["LastName"] = LastNameTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: Just tried and the error is FirstNameTextBox does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You need to add a textbox to the page with ID="FirstNameTextBox" as an example.

Comment: I just want to give an example. If you add a textbox with ID= "FirstNameTextBox" you'll see how to use it when you debug it.